# Error al enviar SMS por Puerto COM y Movil

Tags: vb.net, .net, puertos, mensajes

Hola soy nuevo en esta web por favor quisiera que me ayudaran, veran tengo este coodigo para mandar un sms y funciona al enviarlo pero cuando lo recibo en el movil recibo otra cosa. Ejemplo : mando un "hola" y me llega "(4" en el sms en lugar del texto original. El codigo es el siguiente.

Public Sub enviarSMS(ByVal numero As String, ByVal mensaje As String, ByVal puerto As String)

Dim serialport As SerialPort

```
    Try
        serialport = New SerialPort()

        With serialport
            .PortName = puerto  ' Puerto de comunicaciones COM1, COM2…
            .BaudRate = 9600    ' velocidad del puerto
            .Parity = Parity.None   ' Paridad
            .StopBits = StopBits.One  ' Bit de para
            .DataBits = 8   ' Bits de datos

            If .IsOpen = False Then  ' Si el puerto no esta abierto
                .Open() ' Abrir el puerto
            End If

            .Write(“ATZ0” & vbCr)
            .WriteLine(“AT+CMGF=1” & vbCr) ' Configurando envio de SMS modo texto
            Thread.Sleep(1000) ' Esperar 1 segundo
            .Write(“AT+CMGS=” & Chr(34) & numero & Chr(34) & vbCr)  ' Numero al que se envia el SMS
            .Write(mensaje & Chr(26) & vbCr)
            Thread.Sleep(1000) ' Esperar 1 segundo

            .Close()
            MsgBox(“Mensaje enviado”)

        End With

    Catch Ex As IO.IOException
        'Console.WriteLine(Ex.Message)
    End Try

End Sub
```

Comment: No tengo ni idea de los comandos que estás utilizando, pero intuitivamente veo que `serialport.Write`se compone de un string con un comando y su valor. Por ejemplo haces `AT+CMGS=valor`o `AT+CMGF=valor`, por lo que puedo deducir que al enivar el mensaje también necesites de ese comando, tu haces `.Write(mensaje & Chr(26) & vbCr)`cuando es posible que espere algo del tipo `.Write("comando=" & mensaje & Chr(26) & vbCr)` donde deberías sustituir la palabra comando por lo que diga tu documentación.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta perl he visto muchos ejemplos y documentacion de otros e incluso videos pero ninguno utiliza ningun comando para mandar el sms por el puerto serial es decir que para mandarlo solo se utiliza el .Write (mensaje &chr (26)) sin ningun comando AT

Answer (score 2):

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación similar, dime ¿estas trabajando con un movil o un modem usb conectado al pc?, si es el caso del movil no te aceptara enviar sms con espacios en blanco entre palabras, otra cosa verifica que el puerto COM corresponda al del Modem o Movil conectado.
y otra cosa, en .Portname pon el numero de puerto COM que corresponde al Modem o Movil conectado.

Comment: Gracias, utilizaba mi movil lo raro es que mi aplicacion la probe en una pc diferente y al enviar los sms me llagaron normal, no se que error habia en mi pc o si era mi visual studio pero la aplicacion funcionó de maravilla en otro ordenador.